# Juju + OpenStack (devstack): error, cannot start bootstrap instance, cannot run instance

Tags: juju, openstack

If I want to bootstrap juju with openstack I get the followed output:

```
juju -v bootstrap
verbose is deprecated with the current meaning, use show-log
2014-02-04 13:15:13 INFO juju.environs open.go:156 environment info already exists; using New not Prepare
2014-02-04 13:15:13 INFO juju.provider.openstack provider.go:116 opening environment "openstack"
2014-02-04 13:15:14 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:181 filtering tools by released version
2014-02-04 13:15:14 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:85 reading tools with major.minor version 1.16
2014-02-04 13:15:14 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:96 filtering tools by series: precise
2014-02-04 13:15:14 INFO juju.environs.boostrap bootstrap.go:50 bootstrapping environment "openstack"
2014-02-04 13:15:14 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:181 filtering tools by released version
2014-02-04 13:15:14 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:85 reading tools with major.minor version 1.16
2014-02-04 13:15:14 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:96 filtering tools by series: precise
2014-02-04 13:15:14 INFO juju.environs.boostrap bootstrap.go:71 environs: picked newest version: 1.16.5
2014-02-04 13:15:15 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 cannot start bootstrap instance: cannot run instance: 
    failed to run a server with nova.RunServerOpts{Name:"juju-openstack-machine-0", FlavorId:"42", ImageId:"Juju-Test", 
    UserData:[]uint8{0x1f, 0x8b, 0x8 .... 0x0}, SecurityGroupNames:[]nova.SecurityGroupName{
    nova.SecurityGroupName{Name:"juju-openstack"}, nova.SecurityGroupName{Name:"juju-openstack-0"}}}
    caused by: request (http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8774/v2/a02b07a1a6364b88bc96f305e0ce1ef3/servers) returned unexpected status: 400; 
    error info: {"badRequest": {"message": "Invalid imageRef provided.", "code": 400}}
```

On OpenStack was also no main juju instance created. 
Has someone an idea what goes wrong?